# Whether or not there is an algorithm faster than Euclid for finding GCD

Tags: algorithm, greatest-common-divisor

Is there any algorithm faster than Euclid's algorithm for finding if gcd of two numbers is one?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmer%27s_GCD_algorithm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Binary GCD algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_GCD_algorithm) tends to outperform the Euclidean algorithm.  The idea is to replace division by subtraction and use

```
gcd(a,b) = gcd(a, b-a)
```

and that if a is odd, and b is even, then

```
gcd(a,b) = gcd(a,b/2)
```

which can be implemented as a simple bit operation.

If you are looking for something even faster, there are algorithms [here](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~glmiller/Publications/KMR87.pdf) and [here](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/220224392_An_Improved_Parallel_Algorithm_for_Integer_GCD/file/3deec52375cc1d1269.pdf) that manage to run the binary algorithm in parallel.